# Kubernetes service not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am failing to deploy postgres (single node, official image) on kubernetes and allow services to access postgres via ClusterIP service.

The config is rather simple - Namespace, Deployment, Service:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: database
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: database
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:11.1
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pg
  namespace: database
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgres
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: postgres
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
```

To test is executed a "/bin/bash" into the pod and ran a simple psql command to test the connection. All works well locally:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig $k8sconf -n database exec -it $(kubectl --kubeconfig $k8sconf -n database get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}') -- psql -U admin postgresdb -c "\t"
Tuples only is on.
```

But as soon as I try to access postgres via service, the command fails:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig $k8sconf -n database exec -it $(kubectl --kubeconfig $k8sconf -n database get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}') -- psql -h pg -U admin postgresdb -c "\t"
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "pg" (10.245.102.15) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

This is tested on a DigitalOcean a single node cluster (1.12.3).

Postgres listened on `*` on the correct port, `pg_hba.conf` looks by default like this:

```
...
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
host all all all md5
```

To reproduce see [this gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sontags/c364751e7f0d8ba1a02a9805efc68db6/raw/01b1808348541d743d6a861402cfba224bee8971/database.yaml)

Execute via (please use a fresh cluster and read thru):

```
export k8sconf=/path/to/your/k8s/confic/file
kubectl --kubeconfig $k8sconf apply -f https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sontags/c364751e7f0d8ba1a02a9805efc68db6/raw/01b1808348541d743d6a861402cfba224bee8971/database.yaml
kubectl --kubeconfig $k8sconf -n database exec -it $(kubectl --kubeconfig $k8sconf -n database get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}') -- /bin/bash /reproducer/runtest.sh
```

Any hint why the service does not allow to connect or other tests to perform?

Comment: Just in case anybody experiences the same issue: I have opened an issue at DigitalOcean. It is dispatched to the team in charge of k8s, having their hairpin firewall in mind causing the problem. Nothing sure so far. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell without access to your cluster. This works fine on my AWS cluster. Some things to look at:

- Is the kube-proxy running on all nodes?
- Is your network overlay/CNI running on all nodes?
- Does this happen with the pg pod only? what about other pods?
- DNS seems to be fine since `pg` is being resolved to `10.245.102.15`
- Are your nodes allowing [IP forwarding](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux) from the Linux side?
- Are your Digital Ocean firewall rules allowing traffic from any source on port `5432`?  Note that the PodCidr and K8s Service IP range is different the hostCidr (of your droplets).

Comment: I also tested on GCP with your gist file, works fine

Comment: Its currently for debugging reasons a single node cluster

- kube-proxy on all nodes: Yes
- cni on all nodes: Yes, I assume so.
- Issue on all pods: No. I can curl an other pod which is running a webserver, even spanning namespaces
- DNS: Yes, that works just fine
- IP Forwarding: The node is managend by DigitalOcean. Since everything else works fine (the web server with a Cluster IP and an Ingress upfront for example) I assume that this should be fine.
- Firewall: Since all happens on the only host in the cluster I am quite confident that this should not cause issues.

Comment: I will reproduce on another fresh cluster on DO on raise a ticket if neccessaly